# iOS+SceneKit: How to apply toon shader on texture?

Tags: ios, ios8, textures, shader, scenekit

I want to use a toon-shader with SceneKit on iOS8+ to render a sphere with an Earth texture on it. I also want to add a toon shader for rendering the Earth. So far the shader works on the lighting, but the texture isn't shaded by the toon-shader (cp. to the image below, the texture should also be "tooned").

Someone any ideas?

[image]

Here's my view controller code (self.sceneKitView is an instance of SCNView):

```
@implementation ToonViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];
    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 15);

    // create and add a light to the scene
    SCNNode *lightNode = [SCNNode node];
    lightNode.light = [SCNLight light];
    lightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 10);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:lightNode];

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    SCNNode *ambientLightNode = [SCNNode node];
    ambientLightNode.light = [SCNLight light];
    ambientLightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient;
    ambientLightNode.light.color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:ambientLightNode];

    // set up the scene
    self.sceneKitView.scene = scene;
    self.sceneKitView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    self.sceneKitView.showsStatistics = NO;
    self.sceneKitView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSMutableDictionary* shaders = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    shaders[SCNShaderModifierEntryPointLightingModel] = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"fixed_toon" withExtension:@"shader"]
                                                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                                          error:nil];

    SCNNode* earth = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:5.0]];
    earth.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:earth];

    [earth runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByX:0.0 y:0.25 z:0.0 duration:1.0]]];

    SCNMaterial* earthMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
    earthMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Earth.png"];
    earthMaterial.specular.contents = [UIColor whiteColor];
    earthMaterial.specular.intensity = 0.2;
    earthMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = NO;
    earthMaterial.shaderModifiers = shaders;

    earth.geometry.firstMaterial = earthMaterial;

}

@end
```

And this is the fixed_toon.shader file:

```
vec3 lDir = normalize(vec3(0.1, 1.0, 1.0));
float dotProduct = dot(_surface.normal, lDir);

_lightingContribution.diffuse += (dotProduct*dotProduct*_light.intensity.rgb);
_lightingContribution.diffuse = floor(_lightingContribution.diffuse*4.0)/3.0;

vec3 halfVector = normalize(lDir + _surface.view);

dotProduct = max(0.0, pow(max(0.0, dot(_surface.normal, halfVector)), _surface.shininess));
dotProduct = floor(dotProduct*3.0)/3.0;

//_lightingContribution.specular += (dotProduct*_light.intensity.rgb);
_lightingContribution.specular = vec3(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shader you have is only a lighting shader. If you want the earth to be tooned, you need a fragment shader.

Look at the shader file all of the math is related to light. You need something that will adjust the pixel color of the texture. Then connect it using the SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment entry point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Some more information or links would be highty appreciated. I really did nothing found on the Internet regarding this topic (toon shader for texture in scene kit).

Comment: Another solution would be to make the effect prior in Photoshop for the texture only, but it would be nice to do it by a shader in case of more complex structures.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write the shader for you. A broad outline of what you likely want can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading look specifically at process. Unless you're well versed in shader languages Photoshop will likely be your best solution.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer. I will update the question if I find something suitable.